# Get the locale from a string

Tags: python, regex

if have a problem getting the locale out of a string like:

```
menu_title_en_US
menu_title_en
```

The locale in this string would be "en_US". The string that i have to deal with only have alphanumeric characters and underscores. Like variable names in Python.

I have tried the following regex so far:

```
re.compile(r'_(?P<base_code>[a-z]{2,5})(_(?P<ext_code>[a-z]{2,5})){0,1}$')
```

which is working fine for strings like "menu_en" and "menu_en_US" but for stings like "menu_title_en" or "menu_title_en_US" it's not working as expected (extracting en or en_US).

Maybe someone has a quick idea how to solve this Problem.

Comment: Can you rely on your locale being always `xyz_XYZ` i.e. lower case base code and upper case extended code?

Comment: Hi Howard, yes i can always rely on the local beeing en, en_us or en_US. Same three patterns all the time. But the ext_code can also be uppercase.

Comment: Then everything is fine if you replace the second `[a-z]` by `[A-Z]`, see [here](http://ideone.com/gxfZ6).

Comment: Thanks, one more problem is fixed... There is still one problem left: if i try it with "menu_title_en" the result for base_code is  "title" and for ext_code it's "en". The expected or wished result would be for base_code would be "en" and for ext_code "None" or "". I hope that explains the problem a little better.

Comment: Ah, but how should python know that "title" is no allowed locale? You would have to check it against a whitelist.

Comment: looks like you need a pattern of the form `(en|de|fr|it|.... name your country code|..)` to match the start of the locale reliably.

Comment: That's true. My idea was that the regex ignores all underscore in the string till it finds the last one or second one that matches the pattern for base_code or ext_code. But maybe that's the point to rethink how i try to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Ingo, that would be also possible, but a very loooong regex. :-)

Comment: This works a little bit better:
(_(?P<base_code>[A-Z]{2,5})){0,2}(_(?P<ext_code>[A-Z]{2,5})){0,1}$
(Not at all...)

Comment: @Gernot look at regex in my answer, it works better than that one. So do the non-regex versions.

Comment: Think this works kind of: ( _((?P<base_code>[a-z]{2})_(?P<ext_code>[a-zA-Z]{2}))$ | _(?P<base_code_single>([a-z]{2}))$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the locale is always `en`, `en_us`, or `en_US` (stated in a comment), then you don't need a regex at all:

```
locale = the_string[-6:]
if not locale.startswith('_en_'):
    locale = locale[3:]
locale = locale[1:]
```

or

```
locale = the_string[-3:]
for code in '_en', '_en_us', '_en_US':
    if code.endswith(locale):
        break
else:
    # no locale found
```

You could add more checks if the data could contain something that looked like a locale but wasn't -- these just check for the underscore plus two characters after.

However, the regex can be fixed / simplified a bit, too:

```
re.compile(r'_(?P<base_code>[a-z]{2})(_(?P<ext_code>[a-zA-z]{2}))?$')
```

`?` is the same as `{0,1}`, and since the codes are always two characters you want `{2]` not `{2,5}`. You want to accept either lower or upper case for the second code.

It still will have false positives, though.

Comment: Hi agf, thanks a lot for your help. The problem is that i don't know the locales in advance. Could be anything like xx, xx_xx or xx_XX.

I tried also the following:
      ( _((?P<base_code>[a-z]{2})_(?P<ext_code>[a-zA-Z]{2}))$ | _(?P<base_code_single>([a-z]{2}))$ )

pretty dirty and unsafe, but "kind of works"

Comment: So what did you mean when you said "en, en_us or en_US"? If you don't AT LEAST know the lengths of the codes, there is no way to have any reliability when you tell it from words like "title". If you allow 5 letter codes, then how can you tell "title" from something valid? The regex I give assumes two-letter codes, which I think is reasonable. You just want the first and third groups.

Comment: Wohoo!!! Your regex seem to work fine.
The online regex tester at http://re-try.appspot.com/ seemed to tricked me a lot!

Comment: Sorry agf, you are right. Still getting false positives.But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Gernot like I said, and someone else said in the comments, you need a whitelist in order to do this right. With any type of pattern matching, you'll get false positives.